# In what cases can 'how' replace that?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, grammar, word-choice

> My mom and I both got the iPhone 7+ yesterday. She just text my sister
>   and I **how** she doesn't know how to screenshot on this phone
>
> He told us **how** he was honest and could be trusted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it depends on the situation, and if people actually use the term correctly for what they are trying to say.

> He told us **that** he was honest and could be trusted

He doesn't give you an explaination to why he is honest - just that he is.

> He told us **how** he was honest and could be trusted

He tells you *how* he is honest by gives you examples to convince you, that he is, in fact, honest.

I am no linguistic wizard - but this is how I interpret it, or at least how it *should* be used.

Comment: how to understand the first example?

Comment: He just says: `"I am honest and can be trusted."` In the second example he says: `"Something has happened to me to make me honest and because of that you should trust me."` or something like that.

Comment: sorry but I mean the first example that I presented.

Comment: I would interpret it as thou she has tried many different things, but she cannot get the phone to take a screenshot. If the sentence was: `She just text my sister and I that she doesn't know how to screenshot on this phone`, the text from her could have been like this: `"I don't know how to do it"` - rather than `"I have tried everything but I cannot figure out how to do it"`.

Comment: How means the degree?

Comment: You can say that